# How to build a World to Model Matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, raytracing

I'm currently working on my first ray-tracer and I decided to implement the use of a model to world matrix to transform my camera/primary rays into model space to simply the intersection algorithms of primitive shapes including sphere, planes, cylinders and cones.

In the case of a cylinder, for example, I want to transform the ray origin and direction to test for intersection with cylinder of height 1, radius 1, position (0, 0, 0) and direction/orientation/rotation (0, 1, 0). (xyz format, with x going right, y going up, and z going far).

I also know the ray origin and direction in world space.

How do I determine the world to model transformation matrix for any type of cylinder? (example: height 2, radius 3, position (4, 5, 6) and direction (1, 2, 0))

I am particularly having trouble with properly interpreting the direction of the cylinder and the ray-cylinder intersection algorithm.

Would love some help!

Please note that I have already done plenty of research online about this, and that matrices are not my strong point, but I look forward to reading your suggestions/answers.

Finally, I'm doing this in C, with SDL, math.h and my own functions for matrices etc...

Love!
<3

Answer (score 0):

The best way to position and orientate an object in space is to have a quaternion for it. It basically contains the information for both position and rotation in given space (e.g. world). One can create a quaternion from a simple pair of vectors - position and direction. To apply the transformation stored in such a quaternion a matrix has to be created from it. In a case of ray tracing that would require transforming the ray into model space using inverse matrix for the quaternion of the object (transformation from world to model space, provided ray is in world space), do the intersection in model space, and finally transform the point of intersection back into world space (with the already mentioned, non-inverse, matrix from quaternion).

This is theory. Implementing quaternions by yourself is a chore. It is better to use some exiting library, like GLM for instance. Make sure though it has the required functionalities - creating quaternion from a pair of vectors, casting it to a matrix and inversing the matrix/quaternion.

Comment: Thanks Matso, I will look into using quaternions. Unfortunately, this is a school project and I can only use limited external libraries. I would have to implement quaternions from scratch.